# How to avoid other meshes when creating "cobblestone" with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Inspired by [this popular CG Matter tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA13LPCZ3dM) I set out to make my own object covered in cobblestone. With the method shown in the tutorial the individual stones interlock perfectly, making this technique different from randomly scattering objects.

[image: MWE of my cobblestone.]

However when trying to deal with objects protruding through the cobblestone surface I quickly ran out of ideas to avoid intersections. I would like the stones to stay clear and nicely "incorporate" the red protrusions.

[image: Objects clipping into my cobblestone.]

I tried both the `Raycast` and the `Geometry Proximity` nodes in order to clear out space for my protruding objects but ultimately had no success, especially when trying to account for objects with varying sizes (compared to the "cell-size" of my cobblestone pattern).

The minimal working example can be downloaded here:

[image]

Comment: What about a boolean-difference operation between the pillars and your base object before applying the cobblestone transformation?

Comment: @JagJB good idea, I already tried that. However the boolean algorithm created "indentations" in my mesh. Manually deleting all points inside my red pillars would lead to huge gaps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kept going using the boolean approach and it worked :)

Here is the simple modification to get the result you're looking for I guess.
I scaled up the obstacles in the geonodes to get a nice gap with the stones :

[image]

Here is the file
[image]

Comment: Oh, using the boolean on the triangulated mesh is smart. Okay that should work, thanks a lot!